# How to get TimeZone from android mobile?

Tags: java, android, timezone

I want to get the time zone from the Android mobile when clicking a button.

Comment: TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
    String gmt1=TimeZone.getTimeZone(tz.getID()).getDisplayName(false,TimeZone.SHORT);
    String gmt2=TimeZone.getTimeZone(tz.getID()).getDisplayName(false,TimeZone.LONG);
    Log.d("Tag","TimeZone : "+gmt1+"\t"+gmt2);
    And this is the code

Comment: I wouldn't be so rough on asha v. I was just looking for the same thing and the answers I found were different than these ones. Actually searching by the exact "TimeZone.getDefault" led me here.

Answer (score 241, accepted):

Have you tried to use `TimeZone.getDefault()`:

> Most applications will use **TimeZone.getDefault()** which returns a TimeZone based
>   on the time zone where the program is running.

Ref:  http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html

Comment: If you're using **JodaTime**, you can get a DateTimeZone with the following: `DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());`

Comment: @JoshPinter which package do I use, the one on android.icu.utils or the java.util?

Comment: I changed the time zone from the device to CST, it is not giving me CST back. Is there a way to get the time zone, of the device?

Comment: I'm wondering, does TimeZone.getDefault get effected if we somehow fake the device's timezone. It seems to be not on the android simulator.

Comment: @NeonWarge Both will work, although android.icu only works for API 24 and above.

Comment: This answer is'nt work for me. Result is always UTC

Answer (score 159):

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
System.out.println("TimeZone   "+tz.getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT)+" Timezone id :: " +tz.getID());
```

Output:

> TimeZone   GMT+09:30   Timezone id :: Australia/Darwin

Comment: @Flexo how to get timestamp from android device

Comment: For me, the display name is only EST for TimeZone.SHORT, and Eastern Standard Time for TimeZone.LONG. All i'm looking for is the +/- value lol. Something must have changed.

Comment: @FoxDonut try TimeZone.SHORT_GMT

Answer (score 21):

Edit: corrected the case

[`TimeZone.getDefault()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault())

Answer (score 17):

I needed the **offset** that not only included day light savings time but as a **numerial**. Here is the code that I used in case someone is looking for an example.

I get a response of **"3.5" (3:30')** which is what I would expect in Tehran , Iran in winter and **"4.5" (4:30')** for summer .

I also needed it as a string so I could post it to a server so you may not need the last line.

for getting currect time zone :

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
Date now = new Date();
//Import part : x.0 for double number
double offsetFromUtc = tz.getOffset(now.getTime()) / 3600000.0;
String m2tTimeZoneIs = Double.parseDouble(offsetFromUtc);
```

Comment: It worked for me as I was just dealing with durations (as a stopwatch).

Answer (score 14):

Try this code-

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone tz = cal.getTimeZone();
```

It will return user selected timezone.

Comment: Creating a `Calendar` object for this is a nonsense. The creation of this type of object is expensive. `TimeZone.getDefault()` is the appropriate way to get this.

Comment: @KrLx_roller Please check carefully before downvoting answer. I have wrtitten my answer returns user selected timezone whereas TimeZone.getDefault() will return installation 
default time zone. For more info please http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2037.

Comment: Your code returns the same timezone as TimeZone.getDefault() on android 4.2. TimeZone.getDefault() will return the timezone selected in settings -> date & time.

Answer (score 14):

### ZoneId from java.time and ThreeTenABP

Modern answer:

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
    System.out.println(zone);
```

When I ran this snippet in Australia/Sydney time zone, the output was exactly that:

> ```
> Australia/Sydney
> ```

If you want the summer time (DST) aware time zone name or abbreviation:

```
    DateTimeFormatter longTimeZoneFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("zzzz", Locale.getDefault());
    String longTz = ZonedDateTime.now(zone).format(longTimeZoneFormatter);
    System.out.println(longTz);
    
    DateTimeFormatter shortTimeZoneFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("zzz", Locale.getDefault());
    String shortTz = ZonedDateTime.now(zone).format(shortTimeZoneFormatter);
    System.out.println(shortTz);
```

> ```
> Eastern Summer Time (New South Wales)
> EST
> ```

The `TimeZone` class used in most of the other answers was what we had when the question was asked in 2011, even though it was poorly designed. Today it’s long outdated, and I recommend that instead we use java.time, the modern Java date and time API that came out in 2014.

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- Edit: On (older) Android usually, as long as you're on Android Gradle plugin 4.0 or newer, with `coreLibraryDesugaring` you can use java.time directly. ThreeTenABP is no longer needed. (Previous bullet: use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.)

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Comment: Update to the API level 26 question. ThreeTenABP is no longer needed, usually, as long as you're on Android Gradle plugin 4.0 or newer. With `coreLibraryDesugaring` you can use java.time directly.

Answer (score 12):

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault(); 
timeZone.getID();
```

It will print like

```
Asia/Kolkata
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 6):

On my device, `TimeZone.getDefault()` is always returning the UTC time zone.

I need to do this to get the user-configured time zone:

```kotlin
TimeZone.setDefault(null)
val tz = TimeZone.getDefault()
```

It will return the user-selected time zone.

Comment: Was searching for hours, why `TimeZone.getDefault()` returns UTC always. Thanks for  a solution.

Answer (score 5):

All the answers here seem to suggest setting the daylight parameter to **false**. This is incorrect for many time zones which change abbreviated names depending on the time of the year (e.g., [EST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone) vs. [EDT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone)).

The solution below will give you the correct abbreviation according to the current date for the time zone.

```
val tz = TimeZone.getDefault()
val isDaylight = tz.inDaylightTime(Date())
val timezone = tz.getDisplayName(isDaylight, TimeZone.SHORT)
```

Comment: The `TimeZone` class is poorly designed and long outdated.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest Solution With Simple Date Format: 
**SimpleDateFormat("ZZZZZ"):**

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"),
                Locale.getDefault());
        Date currentLocalTime = calendar.getTime();

        DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("ZZZZZ",Locale.getDefault());
        String localTime = date.format(currentLocalTime);
        System.out.println(localTime+ "  TimeZone   " );
```

==> Output is : +05:30

Answer (score 2):

According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html you should be using Time.getCurrentTimezone() to retrieve the current timezone of the device.

Comment: Cool, but deprecated since API level 22

Answer (score 2):

I have spent some time to find the right answer. [But it seems it works strangely on Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22930726/where-does-android-take-default-timezone-from). My device always returns 'UTC' as a timezoneId, and 0 as a timezone offset. But you can try to use headless WebView and fetch the timezone from there by JS. After this, you can save it into SharedPreference(`TimeZone.setDefault()` also works strangely)

```
class HeadlessWebViewUtil constructor(context: Context) {
    val webView = WebView(context)
    val jsInterface = MyJavaScriptInterface()

    fun fetch() {
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "android")
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:android.onTimezoneFetched(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone)")
    }

    inner class MyJavaScriptInterface {
        @JavascriptInterface
        public fun onTimezoneFetched(timezoneId: String) {
            Timber.d("Timezone fetched: $timezoneId")
        }
    }
}

// And fetch
val wv = HeadlessWebViewUtil(this, timeZoneManager)
wv.fetch()
```

Answer (score 1):

For devices with API  26 and higher, you can get it like this:

```
ZonedDateTime.now().getZone().toString();
```