# Get time from long value

Tags: java, android, time

I am converting milliseconds to the time of the respective country time format, for example, pakistan, US etc

For example
timeinmilliseconds=1549362600000
So its respective Time formate from which I got these milliseconds is 15:30 or 3:30 in 12 hr format
When I want to convert these milliseconds back to that time
I get 10:30 (Five hrs back)

```
public String getTimeFromLong(long timeInMilliseconds){
String mytime="";
long minute = (timeInMilliseconds / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
long hour = (timeInMilliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24;
mytime = String.format("%02d:%02d", hour, minute);
return mytime;
}
```

If I select time 4:00
I converted to that to milliseconds (This part is OK)
And wants the time back from milliseconds but get five hours back
For example, If I select time 9:30
convert it to milliseconds and then to time
I get 4:30

Comment: you are testing on a device ? If yes then this is happening due to GMT +- 5 hours.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Umair How to fix the GMT  +- issue. Yes I am testing it on real device

Comment: Is this method called after converting a time from hh:mm to milliseconds?

Comment: @TajammulShah go through this question you will find what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366276/androiddisplay-time-after-adding-gmt-time-zone

Answer (score 2):

You need to use your local time zone to get the time in your region, the default is being apllied which is the **Greenwich Mean Time (GMT)**.  For Pakistan use `Asia/Karachi` like so:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Karachi"));
```

Comment: You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310.

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to convert milliseconds into your local time

```
public String getTime(long time){
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(time);

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
    Date date = new Date(time);
    String kTime = format.format(date);     
    return kTime;
}
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8 we can do the following.

```
LocalDateTime dateTime =
LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(longValue), ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

to get date and time

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class to use here. Lacking any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC, it cannot represent a moment. You are starting with a moment and then throwing away the valuable zone/offset info with nothing gained.

Answer (score 0):

> Use below code to get time from **long** values:

```
public String getTimeFromLong(long timeInMilliseconds){
 // Creating date format
 DateFormat simple = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS Z");
 Date result = new Date(timeInMilliseconds);
  return simple.format(result);
}
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).